# There are anyway to query the State in Vault without using Schema?

Tags: corda

I'm working with Corda, in case of querying data from Vault of Node. In basic way, I used the Schema to add some criteria for this querying. For example:

`val quantityIndex = SchemaV1.Persistent::value.greaterThanOrEqual(4)`

So, there are anyway to query the State in Vault without using Schema? Because I believe that If I am able to use the class of State instead of Schema class, I can query State with better criteria rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Corda 3, there is no way to do this. This is because other than the properties that are extracted as part of the schema, the state is simply stored as a Java blob.

You'll have to extract the states then filter them in memory:

```
List<StateAndRef<ArtState>> artStateAndRefs = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(ArtState.class).getStates();

StateAndRef<ArtState> inputArtStateAndRef = artStateAndRefs
    .stream().filter(artStateAndRef -> {
        ArtState artState = artStateAndRef.getState().getData();
        return artState.getArtist().equals(artist) && artState.getTitle().equals(title);
    })
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("The piece of art was not found."));
```

If there are a large number of states, you'll have to filter across each vault page individually then collate the results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it runs as well! So, What is the faster solution between using Schema and without Schema?

Comment: Using the schema is much faster, as it executes a database query, instead of going through each object in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your help!